# What do I need to reference here?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

I write this piece of code with C# using ADO.NET Entity Framework.

I found error in here

```
var departmentQuery = from d in schoolContext.Departments.Include("courses")
                              orderby d.Name // here
                              select d;
```

Error message is like the following:

```
Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type
```

I am doing according this articles

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386884.aspx

please point out what do i need to modify?

Thanks in advance!

Best regards,
RedsDevils

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you have the using **System.Linq** in the code. Add a reference for this in project if you are unable to find it in your intellicence.

Answer (score 1):

The only difference I can see between your code and the example is that you have a small "c" in "courses".

Comment: Yea thanks that's too! but it's solved by referencing System.Linq Like Bhaskar says. Thanks anyway.